# How to send selected dropdown value from Django template to a Python file?

Tags: javascript, python, django, bulma

I'm trying to have the user select a value from a dropdown menu and then send that to another file to process it. I got the dropdown from bulma, and I'm having issues understanding how to send data from a template to another file in my Django project.

This is what the dropdown looks like in my Django template:

```
{% block drop-down-button %}
    <div class="dropdown is-active" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div class="dropdown-trigger">
            <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
            <span>AWS Accounts</span>
            <span class="icon is-small">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                558232680640
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">
                903500686888
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                183070076065
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                885703380506
            </a>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                All Accounts
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Please indicate what do you mean by "another file".

Comment: @Lavande - I apologize for the lack of info. another file is called services.py which is inside another app/module in my Django project. Services.py takes care of most things in the website. This dropdown will be used to filter out which AWS account the user wants to see, but I'm having trouble sending the selected value to services.py

Comment: There might be a way to integrate bulma with Django form to implement the post back. However I would prefer to create a JS script here to use AJAX or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), and send the value as a JSON payload back to some particular Django view func/class-based view, or DRF ViewSet first, then send the value to the services.py.

Comment: Note: You will need a custom X-CSRFToken header for either AJAX or FetchAPI approach, please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax